# Excel: percentage change macro excluding non numeric rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some Excel problems and I'd like to get a macro if possible to help me.

**The problem:**

I need to find a percentage difference for a range of columns on one row (A1:A54). Something like `=((max(xy:xy))-(MIN(xy:xy))/(MIN(xy:xy)`

**BUT**

I need excel to exclude rows from the formula which contain something that isn't a number (there are a load of these in random places).

I need something universal so that I can run it in different workbooks etc.

Comment: What other type of data are you seeing.  The worksheet functions max and min skip cells with text in them.

Comment: I've resolved my issues with the worksheet and you're right (although I probably didn't need to reassure you :p). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ignores blanks and text cells

```
Function percentdifference(r As Range) As Double

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        percentdifference = (.Max(r) - .Min(r)) / .Min(r)
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Helper" function like the following in your Macro to check the data type within the cell, and apply the formula only if all the cell is of type "Numeric".

```
Function CellType(c) 
     '   Returns the cell type of the upper left
     '   cell in a range
    Application.Volatile 
    Set c = c.Range("A1") 
    Select Case True 
    Case IsEmpty(c): CellType = "Blank" 
    Case Application.IsText(c): CellType = "Text" 
    Case Application.IsLogical(c): CellType = "Logical" 
    Case Application.IsError(c): CellType = "Error" 
    Case IsDate(c): CellType = "Date" 
    Case InStr(1, c.Text, ":") <> 0: CellType = "Time" 
    Case c.HasFormula: CellType = "Formula" 
    Case IsNumeric(c): CellType = "Numeric" 
    End Select 
End Function
```